# Check if Observable is empty is not possible, so what other option I have?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-observable

I write an angular 11 and I'm pretty new to Observables and Subjects.

I have a `mat-autocomplete` component and it's results are divided to categories. the last category is an articles category and i use this code to display it:

component code:

```
private readonly searchResultArticles = new Subject<Article[]>(); 

get searchResultArticles$(): Observable<Article[]> {
   return this.searchResultArticles;
}
```

template:

```
<mat-optgroup label="Articles">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let article of searchResultArticles$ | async" [value]="article">
          <img class="example-option-img" aria-hidden [src]="getArticleThumbnail(article.profile_dir,article.title)" height="25" />
          <span class="cocktail_name_search_result" *ngIf="article.title" [innerHTML]="article.title | highlight : autoCompleteInput.value : 1"></span>
          &nbsp;-&nbsp;
          <span class="cocktail_desc_search_result" *ngIf="article.desc" [innerHTML]="article.desc | highlight : autoCompleteInput.value : 1"></span>

        </mat-option>
      </mat-optgroup>
```

so `mat-optgroup` with label `Articles` is shown even if there are no items in the `searchResultARticles$` Observable.
I want to be able to hide this `mat-optgroup` if there are no items.

I thought about doing:

```
<mat-optgroup label="Articles" *ngIf="(searchResultArticles$ | async).length>0">
```

but this causes some weird behavior that items sometimes don't show up, i guess i can use async only once? guess i need to read about this some more.

but anyhow.. any elegant way to resolve this ?

thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `*ngIf="(searchResultArticles$() | async).length>0"`? *Emphasis on the () after $*

Comment: @NicholasK no searchResultArticles$ is a get called without ()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first I would like to assign the observable to a `searchResultArticles$` field in the component. Then I assign the result of the async pipeline to a template variable. The hole thing should look like this:

Class code:

```
  searchResultArticles$: Observable<Article[]>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getSearchResultArticles$(): Observable<Article[]> {
    // get articles from somewhere, at best from a separate service class
     return this.http.get<Article[]>(`/articles`);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchResultArticles$ = this.getSearchResultArticles$();
  }
```

Template code:

```
  <mat-optgroup label="Articles" *ngIf="searchResultArticles$ | async as searchResultArticles">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let article of searchResultArticles" [value]="article">
      <img class="example-option-img" aria-hidden [src]="getArticleThumbnail(article.profile_dir,article.title)"
           height="25"/>
      <span class="cocktail_name_search_result" *ngIf="article.title" [innerHTML]="article.title | highlight : autoCompleteInput.value : 1"></span>
      &nbsp;-&nbsp;
      <span class="cocktail_desc_search_result" *ngIf="article.desc" [innerHTML]="article.desc  | highlight : autoCompleteInput.value : 1"></span>

    </mat-option>
  </mat-optgroup>
```

If you like to omit the whole group if searchResultArticles are empty, put it in a `ng-container` as @Thomas suggests

Answer (score 4):

What you need to know is that `async` pipe can return null.

Your approach could be:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="searchResultArticles$ | async as data">
  <mat-optgroup *ngIf="data.length > 0" label="Articles">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: a solution for null things could be ?. operator `data?.length > 0`

Comment: @Andrei in this case not, because you do not want to subscribe twice only to get data and length.